# Openam ssoadm list policies error

Tags: openam

I want to automate my openam setup. I have a weird problem when I try to backup the policies with ssoadm

```
./ssoadm list-policies -u amAdmin -f /tmp/pwd.txt -e / -o /tmp/policies.txt

"null"
```

this is the only error that ssoadm gives to me, then If I check the error log of ssoadm I see:

```
""2014-07-21 09:10:22"   /|com.miimetiq.identity.policy.RoleCondition    id=amAdmin,ou=user,dc=openam    5753f489d4161201     "Not Available" INFO    dc=openam       "cn=dsameuser,ou=DSAME Users,dc=openam" AMCLI-2442      ssoadm.error"Not Available"  192.168.100.10"
```

Do you have any idea what is this error? anything related with dns settings of the domain maybe?

output of /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
#127.0.1.1 test.miimetiq.com test
192.168.100.10 test.miimetiq.com test
```

Domain of openam is in my scenario: test.miimetiq.com:8080/openam

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be related to your custom PolicyCondition implementation. When using ssoadm you should make sure that custom policy extensions are available on the classpath.

Comment: Hi Peter, How can I check that? I understand that only way to do that is with webserver of openam (tomcat in 8080) ???

Comment: I want to specify that the policies were made one by one not using ssoadm but the web interface of openam. The problem is then as I explained before I can't list them with ssoadm :(

Comment: In your question the audit log entry was quite descriptive: "com.miimetiq.identity.policy.RoleCondition"

Comment: Hi Peter I made some test yesterday and as you realized the problem was that some policies had "Role Condition" with some value. After remove RoleCondition we could list the policies. My question now is..how can we maintain the Role Condition and list the policies by command?

Comment: Also I have verified that it don't only happens with RoleCondition but also with "UrlContainsCondition". Any condition in any policy don't let me to list policies with ssoadm !!!

Comment: Again, you should add those custom extensions to the ssoadm classpath by editing the ssoadm/ssoadm.bat script.

Comment: Hi I want to comment that the answer of Peter Major was right. Once I set the variable CLASSPATH with the value of custom policy extensions, ssoadm was able to import policies.